# Deterministic Surrogate Key

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have a table with an integer identity column as a surrogate key for two other columns (int and datetime). To keep the value of this key in sync across test and production environments, I had the idea to make a trigger that sets the surrogate key to some deterministic value instead of the auto-generated identity (in this case a hash of the natural key). The tradeoff, as far as I can tell, is that I introduce the risk of collisions (which can be offset by changing the surrogate column to bigint).

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_TestTable_SetID ON dbo.TestTable 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    insert into dbo.TestTable (ID, IntKey, DateKey, MoreData)
    select convert(bigint, hashbytes('md5', convert(binary(4), IntKey) + convert(binary(8), DateKey))), 
        IntKey, DateKey, MoreData
    from inserted
END
```

Is this a good solution from a design standpoint? Will it still perform better than using the natural composite key as the primary key?

Edit: The int in the natural key is a foreign key to another table, where it is the surrogate key for a guid and a varchar. So the "natural key" alternative on this table would be the rather ugly composite of guid, varchar, and datetime.

Comment: No. even with bigint you will soon have collisions (see: birthday paradox). Why do you need both a surrogate key and deterministic based on the source columns?

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks for reply. See edit: using the natural key in this case would make for tedious and inefficient querying (particularly in joins). I was hoping to get the benefits of a single key, without the downside of this number having to be random (hence deterministic).

Comment: I sad nothing about the natural keys. You said that you wanted to replace an int and datetime key with a deterministic surrogate bigint.  There's no significant performance nor useabilty advantage for an 8-byte key over the already existing 12-byte key.  So the question remains, why do you need or want this new surrogate key and why do you need it to be deterministic?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I was thinking surrogate key both because it is smaller and a single key is better than a composite key. Deterministic to make different environments with copies of the database to have the same key values. It's sounding like I should just bite the bullet and go with the natural keys.

Comment: Your claim that using natural keys would make querying tedious and inefficient does not ring true. Are you trying to join a test table to a production table? Otherwise, I don't see a problem that requires a deterministic value?

Comment: What?  A single key is better than a composite key?  LOL.  The indiscriminate use of surrogate keys was largely promoted by ORM technologies and the mindset, "If I do it anywhere I should do it everywhere."  The only time a composite key underperforms (and in many cases it will outperform surrogate keys as in many cases, the index contains the value and there's no table access required) is when one of the columns can be null - bad practice, but I've seen it.

Answer (score 4):

I have used similar techniques before for similar reasons and with good success. To get the deterministic qualities that you want, you might try coercing the the composite natural key column values to strings, string-concatenating them together, and then generating an MD5 hash from that to use as your deterministic primary key.

Some considerations:

- **Case-sensitivity.** Unless some of your business keys are meant by design to be case-sensitive, it is a good idea to establish a convention in your system to downcase or upcase letters first as 'a' is not the same as 'A' to a hash function. This can help avoid issues if you are creating a key from possibly manually user keyed data. For example, if a user keyed in item number 'itm009876' instead of 'ITM009876', and your various source systems aren't robust enough to conform the value before storing them.
- **String coercion**: Make sure that you coerce values into strings in a way that makes sense and is very specific. For example, using ISO dates and date times plus time zone, or converting dates and date times to Unix timestamp integers before coercing to string
- **String delimiter.** Use a good string separater between the strings before concatenation, such as ';'. (E.g., string concatenation of A+CB should not be the same as AB+C)
- **Store hash as binary**: If possible store the MD5 hash as a 16-byte binary value on the table, and use a HEX() function to display it in a human readable format. Storing an MD5 hash as binary uses exactly half of the amount of space it would take to store a 32 byte hexadecimal string, which has advantages for performance of lookups and joins because it is both shorter and completely avoids any possible cycles wasted on special string comparison logic.

**Pros**

- May avoid accidental duplication of row data at times
- May avoid unnecessary round trips to single authority that must generate or retrieve serial or UUID surrogate keys.
- Single column keys are easier for end users work with.
- Single column keys are easier for downstream developers writing SQL, generating urls, etc to work with.
- MD5 is old and well established so it's very well supported as an SQL function by most DBMS, so you can use compute them there too as needed without and third party extensions.
- With MD5, collisions are extremely rare. As in more likely that your data center gets destroyed by a meteor than to experience a collision, even with hundreds of billions of rows and a single table. There is quite a bit of robust discussion about this online if you Google for one popular methodology that employs hash keys: 'data vault hash keys'.

**Cons**

- Collisions are of course still theoretically possible with MD5. Many organizations are still very hesitant about this. So if you must have more bytes on the hash space, and you can live with the potential performance hit during joins and index updates, you can always choose a longer SHA hash.
- Generation is complicated. You must choose and document the algorithm for generating the composite key hashes very well and communicate well with other developers in the organization. Just make sure that everyone is doing it the same way.
- because of the non-sequential nature of hashes, they can be inefficient to query in some scenarios, such as in clustered index tables. Be careful with this as some DBMS's use clustered index as the default - or may not even have any other option - such as MYSQL's InnoDB. Heap tables are generally better, such as is supported/default in PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

(Sorry for any typos and grammar mistakes. I am writing this on my mobile phone. I'll try to come back later and clean it up.)